# c++ fstream don't print symbols like ρ and Δ to file correctly

Tags: c++, windows, fstream

I get a messed up result when using fstream to print these symbols to file.
using:

```
file << "Δ" << endl;
```

This works fine in Linux, but when i compilled it for windows it don't work.

Is there a specific way of making this work in windows?

Comment: I don't think Windows consoles support Unicode characters

Comment: @TonyTheLion: The OP is writing to a file.

Comment: Did you check used encodings? In Linux it's probably UTF-8, but in Windows, without BOM it will probably default to your local codepage.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work on MSVC2010. Use [std::codecvt_utf8_utf16](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16) to covert wide characters to UTF-8 byte stream:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>
int main() 
{
    std::wofstream file("myfile", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    file.imbue(std::locale(file.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>));

    file << L"Δ" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @lasvig code::blocks is just an IDE, not a compiler. It depends on which compiler you use (which I would guess is MinGW that came packed with your code::blocks download).

Comment: @lasvig: I don't think mingw supports this yet. You could use [utf8_codecvt_facet](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/codecvt.html) from boost probably.